# Multiple threshold lines with love plot R

Tags: r, cobalt

Is there a way to add multiple threshold lines to the `love.plot` below? Also, I can't seem to figure out how to suppress the `NA` variables from being displayed.

```
love.plot(bal.tab(gac_status ~ covs, data = new_data),
          binary = "std",
          sample.names = "Difference",
          title = "Covariate Balance \n Mean Treated minus Mean Control",
          position = "none",
          stars = "raw",
          drop.missing = TRUE,
          thresholds = c(m = 0.1)) +
         labs(caption = "* indicates variables for which the displayed value is the raw (unstandardized) difference in means.")
```

I tried thresholds = c(m=c(0.1,0.05)) but that didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a ggplot object so `+ geom_vline(xintercept = ...)` works.